# How to save VBA in a in or as Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I know How to Run a macro which is Recorded in Macro-enabled excel file but in case of Creating a Macro in Visual basic application - from a module I do not know how to save and run them for future use? Is there any way that I can save cosdes in visual basic As a MACRO? so user just run it from the list of existing Macros?

Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Read up on google on storing macros in personal file.

Comment: Do I have to save the personal.xls in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART for sure? Because my computer doesn't let me to save at that directisn!

Comment: `1` What is your operating system? `2` Is it 32 bit or 64 bit? `3` Do you have Rights to save the file at that location? You might not if you are on say an office pc

Comment: it is 64/ No permission

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/personal.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Can you please let me know how to fix this?`

Follow these steps

Open your VBE ( Visual Basic Editor ) with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (*or `Developer` tab then `Visual Basic`*)

Right-click the VBA Project and `Insert` a `Module` (*Standard coding module* - not a class nor userform)

Copy-Paste the below code

```
Sub YouCanSeeMe()
    MsgBox "I am visible in the list of macros!"
End Sub

Private Sub YouCannotSeeMe()
    MsgBox "I am not shown in the list because I am private" & vbCrLf & _
            "You can only call me from VBA Code"
End Sub

Public Sub IAmPublic()
    MsgBox "I am public so you can see me"
End Sub

Public Sub IAmPublicButYouCannotSeeMe(Optional bool As Boolean)
    MsgBox "I am public but you can't see me in the list of macros " & vbCrLf & _
            "because I need a parameter to run!"
End Sub
```

now, go back to the `Developer` tab and click Macros ( or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> in the spreadsheet view )

You should now see which subs are visible in the list  and which are not.

[image]

As you can see it's all down to the access modifiers (Public/Private or default which is Public) and also the visibility in the macros list depends on the amount of parameters Sub requires.

Note there is also a `Friend` keyword but it's not relevant in this case. You can google it if you want though.

---

now if you wanted to save some macros for future make sure that your Explorer is showing you all hidden files because `AppData` is a hidden folder and if you don't see hidden files then you can't save your personal workbook in there.

Full description step-by-step is [**here**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-HA102174076.aspx)

but in easy words

you can save the workbook you just made with the above code in

> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

save is as `Excel Binary Workbook` or `.xlsb` extension.

Now everytime you start Excel you have access to the macros that were saved in that workbook.

Note this only works on *your* machine.